# lowest sum of negative integer elements in an array with the option to skip elements but no two consecutive

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array of negative integers such as:

{-1,-3,-4,-10,-22,-2}

I am trying to find the sum closest to 0. It is permitted that numbers can be skipped but not consecutively.  ie. in the above example, the possibilities are -1, -4, -22 or -1, -3, -10, -2 etc.

The answer to the above array is -3, -10, -2 = -15

I have a solution that uses recursion, but I was wondering if anyone can think of a simpler solution that I am missing?

```
 private static int maxSum(int in[]){
     return maxSum(in,0,in.length==1) ;
 }

 private static int maxSum(int in[], int off, boolean skipped){
     if(off == in.length){
         return 0;
     }
     else if(in.length - off >= 1){
         if(skipped){
             return in[off] + maxSum(in,off+1,false);
         }
         else{
             int w0 = maxSum(in,off+1,true);
             int wn0 = in[off] + maxSum(in,off+1,false);
             return Math.max(w0,wn0);
         }
     }
     else {
         throw new RuntimeException();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand this part *can be skipped but not consecutively*... you say that `{-7,-1,-2,-6}` should produce `-3`; but how come in the initial example `{-1,-3,-4,-10,-22,-2}` the result is not `-4` (first two)?

Comment: If the first two were taken, then you would be skipping -4, -10, -22 and -2.  You could in theory skip -3 but then you couldn't skip -4.  Does it make sense?

Comment: so you could have taken for example: -1, -3, -4, -22, -2 if it would fit, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Since all the elements are negative, and you can't skip more than two elements in a row, the sum closest to 0 will either be the sum of all the odd indexed elements of the sum of all the even indexed elements (since you want to skip as many elements as you are allowed to).

Compute both of these sums and return the higher of them:

```
private static int maxSum(int in[]) {
    int odd = 0;
    int even = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            even += in[i];
        } else {
            odd += in[i];
        }
    }
    return Math.max(odd,even);
}
```

For

```
System.out.println (maxSum(new int[]{-1,-3,-4,-10,-22,-2}));
```

it prints

```
-15
```

Comment: Great answer dude

Comment: @Eran left this one as "to answer later" - only to see you already did :) +1

Comment: Great idea, but this wouldn't work for this situation:        System.out.println(maxSum(new int[]{-7,-1,-2,-6}));    The answer should be -3.

Comment: @YodaGenes good catch. I didn't consider such case. Let me think about it some more.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Eran said (a bit too late), but via Stream API in java-8:

```
int[] x = { -1, -3, -4, -10, -22, -2 };

Map<Boolean, Integer> map = IntStream.range(0, x.length)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                    i -> i % 2 == 0,
                    Collectors.summingInt(i -> x[i])));

    System.out.println(Math.max(map.get(Boolean.FALSE), map.get(Boolean.TRUE)));
```